# Only show PHP error messages to Super Admin

Tags: error-handling, error-reporting

Is there a way to show **PHP error messages only** to a **Super Admin**?

How are PHP error messages called or generated?

I know in **System Configuration** we can set the level e.g. developer or none, would there be a way to wrap that in a PHP statement to only output it if they are Super Admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a current extension in the JED that says it allows you to output to specific levels. https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/miscellaneous/development/easy-error-reporting/

Free to download so even if you don't use it you could have a look under the covers as to how they have achieved it.

Comment: A remarkably simple plugin, great work by Victor.  I'll install it, such a good idea

Answer (score 0):

This should help you, https://extensions.joomla.org/blog/item/debug-system/

And in case the link no longer works in the future, the solution requires you to go into the Plugin Syste - Debug and change the access level to 'Super User' and then turn on Debug is Gloal Configuration.

Comment: That is useful and in fact the look has changed since then.  But I am talking about PHP errors not debugging.

Comment: @Eoin sorry about that, a bit early in the morning. :)